# CE 1.9.2 - Date of Birth validation at checkout not working

Tags: checkout, date, form-validation, onestepcheckout

I cannot for the life of me understand what is happening with the Date of Birth field in Checkout or Registration. I've set it as Required under *Customer Configuration*, and have the date fields order set as Day, Month, Year.

But on the checkout screen, I keep getting an error:

> "Date of Birth" is a required value.

If I leave the field as optional, and still fill in data, the order goes through, but the field is blank in the admin backend for my test customer.

I followed similar posts and see that `/js/varien/js.js` already has the change around line 442 for the `parseInt` function. I haven't overridden anything from Core in this regard, but I am using the free OneStepCheckout extension from Lotus Breath.

Any advice?

Comment: If you set the date of birth filed is required, then you login customer must be update DOB otherwise getting an error

Comment: Is the DOB field shown in checkout?

Comment: Hi Roman. Yes, it is

Comment: could you fix this?

Comment: hey nano, no unfortunately not for the default one-page checkout. But we did implement a OneStep Checkout (not to solve it) which weirdly sorted the problem out!

Comment: I don't understand the question. If one would update the question with steps to reproduce I might find some time to look into it, sounds interesting. For the moment I vote to close it.